# setting wordpress in linux

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu

What's the best way of setting wordpress in linux ( ubuntu 22.04 ) ?

I tried using xampp , I have been getting errors that it can't connect to the database despite the database being active and the credentials being okay.

Tried using docker , facing permission blockage despite the fact , I am operating as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAMP(Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP), maybe while using docker is a little bit tricky, or try using WordPress Docker official image in the docker hub.

for reasons of ease, use LAMP + phpMyAdmin for managing the database.

Answer (score 0):

So many options when you have a Linux system available! You can run WordPress on the native (LAMP) stack. But Xampp and Docker should also work...

What is the best way? Depends on the purpose of your WordPress website and what else you have running on the Linux host. If you need to have any dependencies separated from other stuff that is running on the system then you might want to retry running it in Docker. What was your permission issue? If you have *AppArmor* active that is maybe interfering with the setup?

If you have this Ubuntu system dedicated for your website then why not run it on a native LAMP stack? Not really sure why you would need Xampp on Linux, maybe most components are installed and configured for you which makes it easier to setup (although you ran into db problems). But if you follow one of the many guides out there, like [this](https://linuxhint.com/set-up-lamp-stack-ubuntu-22-04/) one, it's not that complicated to install a LAMP-stack.

Of course, if you want to make this site publicly accessible, I would consider your configuration very carefully because of potential security issues. Adding a firewall, hardening the system and keeping everything up-to-date.

Comment: Someone recommeded me to use : https://localwp.com/ it's  easier to use and handles all configurations in the linux machine.

Comment: Hm never used it but it looks handy indeed. Especially if you're going to run multiple sites on this host.